# Optimize .htaccess file rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, optimization, policy

my .htaccess file is like following, after reading many articles, blogs, website. I have designed it, but i know after all this it became like a clutter and there is still scope of sanitizing and perfection in it.
Please suggest me how to optimize in best way.

This code majorly talks about

**1)** Redirect rules

**2)** Content Security Policy

**3)** Optimized content delivery

**4)** Declaration of MIME Types

---

```html
> `ServerSignature Off
php_value max_input_vars 40000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 40000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 40000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 40000

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# BEGIN (mt) controlled settings
    <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
        AddHandler php-stable .php
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        FcgidWrapper /etc/apache2/gs-bin/php-stable-wrapper .php
        <Files *.php>
            Options +ExecCGI
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
# END (mt) controlled settings
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# DECLARING MIME TYPES
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    AddType text/html .html
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType font/woff .woff
    AddType font/woff2 .woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   .eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          .ttf .ttc
    AddType font/opentype                   .otf
</IfModule>
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# EXTRA SECURITY HEADERS IN COOKIES
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    # Header set X-Frame-Options: DENY

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.websitename.com/"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-accept-charset, X-accept, X-test-header, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Type"
    Header set x-xhr-request "true"

    Header set Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
    Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict"

    Header set Content-Security-Policy:     "default-src 'self' https://*.youtube.com ; frame-ancestors 'none'; connect-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' blob: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google-analytics.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com ; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' https://www.cartonrent.com/images/logo.png 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data: www.google-analytics.com https://cartonrent.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; worker-src 'self' www.google.com https://maps.google.com "
    Header set X-Content-Security-Policy:   "default-src 'self' https://*.youtube.com ; frame-ancestors 'none'; connect-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' blob: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google-analytics.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com ; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' https://www.cartonrent.com/images/logo.png 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data: www.google-analytics.com https://cartonrent.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; worker-src 'self' www.google.com https://maps.google.com "
    Header set X-WebKit-CSP:                "default-src 'self' https://*.youtube.com ; frame-ancestors 'none'; connect-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' blob: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google-analytics.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com ; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' https://www.cartonrent.com/images/logo.png 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data: www.google-analytics.com https://cartonrent.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; worker-src 'self' www.google.com https://maps.google.com "

    Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "master-only"
    Header always set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
    #Header always set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header always set Expires "-1"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"

    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(css|png|js)$">
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# REWRITE RULES
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

   # Recursive rule to replace space by - from URI OR query string (anywhere)
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R]

    # Recursive rule to replace space by - from URI OR query string (anywhere)
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R]

    # URL Canonicalization (adding www. prefix to URL)
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.websitename.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Deny pages from all except XMLHttpRequest
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-REQUESTED-WITH} !^(XMLHttpRequest)$
        RewriteRule table-view+.php$ - [L,F]

 </IfModule>

  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
  # RewriteRule .* - [F]

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# Keep Connection Alive
   <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Connection keep-alive
   </ifModule>

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# SET THE DEFAULT LANGUAGE
    DefaultLanguage en-US

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# SET THE DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# IMAGEMAGIK IMAGE COMPRESSION LIMIT
    SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 2
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# NO Etags
    FileETag none

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# PREVENT FOLDER LISTING
    IndexIgnore *

# DISABLE DIRECTORY BROWSING
    Options All -Indexes

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# COMPRESS TEXT, HTML, JAVASCRIPT, CSS, XML, fonts:

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vtt
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/js
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon

    # OR, COMPRESS CERTAIN FILE TYPES BY EXTENSION:

    <files *.html>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </files>

    # Java script compression
    <FilesMatch "\.js$">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
        RewriteRule (.*)\.js$ $1\.js.gz [L]
        ForceType text/javascript
    </FilesMatch>


    # Java script - vary accept encoding
    <FilesMatch "\.js\.gz$">
        ForceType text/javascript
        Header set Content-Encoding gzip
        Header set Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>

    #Enable gzip with mod_gzip
    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
        mod_gzip_on Yes
        mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
        mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
        mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
    </ifModule>

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# DENY ACCESS TO EVIL ROBOTS SITE RIPPERS OFFLINE BROWSERS AND OTHER NASTY SCUM

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Anarchie [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ASPSeek [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^attach [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^autoemailspider [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xenu [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus.*Webster [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# SERVE CUSTOM ERROR PAGES

    ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# SETTINGS FOR PHP ERROR LOGING

# SUPPRESS PHP ERRORS FROM DISPLAYING IN THE BROWSER
    php_flag display_startup_errors off
    php_flag display_errors off
    php_flag html_errors off

# LOG PHP ERRORS TO A FILE
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 32767
    php_value error_log "errorlog/error.log"

# DISABLE LOGGING REPEATED ERRORS
    php_flag ignore_repeated_errors on

# PREVENT ACCESS TO PHP ERROR LOG
    <Files error.log>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
      Satisfy All
    </Files>

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# Zlib Configuration
    <ifModule mod_php4.c>
         php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
    </ifModule>

# handler for phpsuexec..
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|style)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

# Force “File Save As” Prompt for following files
    AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
    AddType application/octet-stream .zip
    AddType application/octet-stream .mov

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #`
```